# How to narrow down union of generic types in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a form component in React that uses generic types.

The generic type for the form is the initialValues that are passed in.

I can't for the life of me seem to get Typescript to narrow down the type that corresponds to a particular field.

[Here's a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-nobel-rc2bj?file=/src/Example.tsx) with one of my many attempts at trying to get this to work correctly.

I've tried many other things, like adding a 'type' property to each of the fields and then using a switch statement to try and narrow it down that way, but none of them have seemed to work!

Not looking anyone to write this code for me, but a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you've probably guessed by now, to do this you can't just define an indexable type like

```
type FormValues<T> = {
  [key: string]: T
}
```

Because `T` in this case will be a union that doesn't help too much.

So you can't use indexable type, now the only way I can think stop trying to create the type yourself and just let typescript infer it for you.

Firstly let me change your `FormValue` declaration a bit, I'll remove `ValueOf`, while I was playing with your sandbox I forgot what was its purpose, but if I don't think it matters in the way I'm suggesting. So let's type it like this:

```
type FormValue<TName extends string, TValue> = {
  value: TValue
  name: TName
  pristine: boolean
  errors: string[] | null
}
```

Now this will just take two type arguments, one is the name, another is the value, no unnecessary objects. Now let's type `InitialFormValues`: it will be just an object with random properties, we won't use it to type anything, only to constraint types:

```
type InitialValues = {
  [key: string]: any
}
// or
type InitialValues = Record<string, any>
```

Next comes `UseFormProps`. Here we avoid creating indexable type, that doesn't lead to anything, but we let typescript infer the type for us. We only need to constraint it a bit so that it's not possible to pass p.e. a number as `initialValues`:

```
type UseFormProps<T extends InitialValues> = {
  initialValues: T
}
```

Now typescript will automatically choose `T` and it will be exactly what we need: if `initialValues` is `{ foo: 1, bar: 'str' }`, it will be `{ foo: number, bar: string }` and nothing more.

Last goes `FormValues`:

```
type FormValues<T extends InitialValues> = {
  [x in keyof T]: FormValue<x, T[x]>
}
```

Now `FormValues` will not be just indexable, but it will contain exactly the properties `T` contains, also `T[x]` will not be a union like `T[keyof T]`, it will be different for each value of `x` so for each property. That's basically it, now it should work as expected. You'll only need to change something in `transformInitialValues`, because typescript will now complain if you assign empty object to `FormValues<whatever>`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Wonderfully detailed explanation as well.
Just tried out the things you mentioned and it works exactly the way I had been trying for.
Thanks so much for taking the time to do that, really appreciate it!